# PHP - Form protection examples

Tags: php, codeigniter, sanitization, xss

Is there a list of example attacks that can be used to test a PHP form?

In particular it is for a forum, which is using a parser to parse bbcode and doesn't accept HTML directly.

At the moment it runs through codeigniters xss_clean function as well as htmlspecialchars.

If it makes any different it runs htmlspecialchars_decode() when putting the data back into an input or textarea for editing, but not when displaying normally.

There are some areas I don't fully understand (not ever having tried to hack a website) such as someone posting an image which runs through a script or adding additional lines of javascript to an image. So I'm mainly looking for examples that I can put into my form to test if it handles it.

I should note that I have avoided using strip_tags as it messes up in various instances such as:

> If I type X < Y then it will strip everything after the X

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't accept it as the answer since it was a comment but @ComFreek gave a really useful link just put these into your forms to check for errors.

Lots of them are only found in older browsers though particularly old versions of IE

[ha.ckers.org/xss.html](http://ha.ckers.org/xss.html)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using CodeIgniter's `html_escape` function instead of `htmlspecialchars`. Not only can you come back and add security to all your output from one centralized place since it's a function, but it also **sanitizes arrays**.

Also check [this](http://www.sk89q.com/2009/08/definitive-php-security-checklist/) out. Link is working, the server just seems to be down for the moment. [Here](http://www.sk89q.com/content/2010/04/phpsec_cheatsheet.pdf) is the 'short' version.

Comment: Interesting to say use it on the output, that would use far more server resources since it would be run god knows how many times on thousands of page loads. Imagine a topic page which lists 30 comments, each with comment text, signatures and 5-10 pieces of profile information in the sidebar for each user. That could require xss_clean being run 200-300 times on that one page load compared to just when the data is first saved to the database.

Comment: Hit enter forgetting it would submit... As for the links the cheat sheet is useful but not exactly what i'm looking for. I've already tried to ensure various security essentials, i'm now looking for attacks that I can copy and paste into my forms to test them :) But I will look at html_escape i've been using CI so long that I forget some of the functions it possesses :D

Comment: Just another comment, html_escape looks good. I was frustrated by the use of set_rule not allowing me to set the charset, meaning that I had to run htmlspecialchars outside of it, but html_escape automatically uses the charset set in my config so it's perfect